# How to display numeric memory under the slider bar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm making sliders bar.
I want to put a memory like 0 1 2 3 4 under the slider like in the picture
Same as bar length.

Ideal one
[image]

Mine

[image]

How can I make it look like the ideal?

My code is like this now.

```
          <input className="col-8" type="range" name="speed" min="0" max="100" 
          value={brightness_value} onChange={handleSliderChange}></input><br></br>
          <br></br>
          <p>0 1 2 3 4</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the range marks using CSS Flexbox:

```html
<div class="range-marks">
    <span>0</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

```css
.range-marks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Put the **input** element and **range marks** inside a **container** and make **input width 100%**. Change the width of the whole control by applying CSS or classes (e.g. `col-8`) to the container element.

### Result:

```css
.range-marks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.range-input {
  width: 100%;
}

.range-container {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-container">
  <input class="range-input" type="range" name="speed" min="0" max="100" />

  <div class="range-marks">
    <span>0</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n9e61k0L/

Answer (score 0):

you can control `<p>` width and letter spacing for fix the position

```css
input { 
    width: 200px;
}

p { 
    width: 200px;
    letter-spacing: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input className="col-8" type="range" name="speed" min="0" max="4" 
          value={brightness_value} onChange={handleSliderChange}></input><br></br>
          <br></br>
          <p>0 1 2 3 4</p>
```